# eBay template HTML editor

Tags: windows, text-editor, html-editor, ebay

I'm looking for an application (some editor etc.) that can help in creating eBay auction templates. Do you know any?

I want it to be dedicated for eBay (if any exists) - I mean, it should serve eBay variables and could have something validator-like (which validates HTML tags, that can be used on eBay - e.g. some HTML5 tags work there and some not). It can also support some plugings/features for eBay - like auction lister, category creator, etc.).

I use Windows :)

I can buy the software, it needn't be a freeware.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example, what are your exact requirements towards functionality? What OS should it run on? Do you mean templates in the sense of design – or in the sense of automation?

Comment: Sorry mate, new here :)

Comment: No prob, Nickon – that's what we "elders" are here for :) Still missing ***to mention the OS it should run on*** (Android, iOS, Linux, OSX, Windows…). Some background on your intended workflow might also prove helpful for "good answers".

Comment: Any propositions?:)

Comment: Not me. But now that we have all the details, hopefully someone else can come up with an answer :)